# Formulario de estrellas, redireccionar según las que se puntúe

Tags: php, javascript, formularios

Tengo un simple formulario de estrellas (1 estrella a 5 estrellas).

Necesito que si por ejemplo, el usuario puntúa con 2 estrellas (o menos) redireccione a una página, y si puntúa con 3 estrellas o más redireccione a otra.

Encontré por aquí un ejemplo de las estrellas, pero no encuentro nada que haga lo de la redirección.

```js
$(".clasificacion").find("input").change(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val()
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").removeClass("activo")
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").each(function(index) {
    if (index + 1 <= valor) {
      $(this).addClass("activo")
    }

  })
})

$(".clasificacion").find("label").mouseover(function() {
  var valor = $(this).prev("input").val()
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").removeClass("activo")
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").each(function(index) {
    if (index + 1 <= valor) {
      $(this).addClass("activo")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.clasificacion input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.clasificacion label {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clasificacion label:hover {
  color: rgb(217, 215, 11);
}

.activo+label {
  color: rgb(255, 230, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="clasificacion">
  <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
  <label for="radio1">★</label>
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
  <label for="radio2">★</label>
  <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
  <label for="radio3">★</label>
  <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
  <label for="radio4">★</label>
  <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
  <label for="radio5">★</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tienes todo lo que necesitas para hacer lo que buscas, por ejemplo, ya guardas el valor seleccionado en la variable `valor`, entonces solo haz un if según dicho valor, algo asi:

```js
$(".clasificacion").find("input").change(function(){
  var valor = $(this).val()
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").removeClass("activo")
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").each(function(index){
     if(index+1<=valor){
      $(this).addClass("activo")
     }
  })
  /*aqui agregas lo que necesitas hacer según el valor*/
  
  if(valor==1){
  alert('redireccion del valor 1');
  }
  if(valor==2){
  alert('redireccion del valor 2');
  }
  if(valor==3){
  alert('redireccion del valor 3');
  }
  if(valor==4){
  alert('redireccion del valor 4');
  }
  if(valor==5){
  alert('redireccion del valor 5');
  }
})

$(".clasificacion").find("label").mouseover(function(){
  var valor = $(this).prev("input").val()
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").removeClass("activo")
  $(".clasificacion").find("input").each(function(index){
     if(index+1<=valor){
      $(this).addClass("activo")
     }     
  })
})
```

```html
<style>
        .clasificacion input[type='radio'] {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .clasificacion label {
    font-size: 30px;
    color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .clasificacion label:hover {
    color: rgb(217, 215, 11);
  }
   .activo + label{
   color: rgb(255, 230, 0) !important;
   }
    </style>
    <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="clasificacion">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1"><!--
    --><label for="radio1">★</label><!--
    --><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2"><!--
    --><label for="radio2">★</label><!--
    --><input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3"><!--
    --><label for="radio3">★</label><!--
    --><input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4"><!--
    --><label for="radio4">★</label><!--
    --><input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5"><!--
    --><label for="radio5">★</label>
  </p>
```

Obviamente en tu ejemplo usa un `window.location` (por ejemplo) para la redireccion en lugar del `alert`. Suerte.

Comment: Perfecto, yo me estaba complicando la vida haciendo con PHP, pero con javascript así está perfecto. Gracias.

Comment: Puedo reabrir tema, porque lo estoy pasando a react, y no podria usar if, edité el tema.

Comment: @MatiST00 por favor no replantees la pregunta así, lo mejor sería que formularas una pregunta nueva. Saludos.